# Router internet connection drops when my Mac goes sleep mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a very strange issue with my home network.

I have a router (TP-Link Archer C7) that brings me an internet connection by ethernet and WIFI. It works well until my Mac, which is plugged directly by ethernet cable to the router, goes into sleeping mode. Then I have no internet connection on all my devices connected by WIFI. If I turn on my Mac back on, the internet connection comes back... I don't have any idea what can cause this issue. I have barely learned some basics about network and I can't figure it out with my knowledge...

Comment: I have not seen that before (multiple locations).  Is your MAC Ethernet Connection a vanilla DHCP connection?  Not static or any other special settings?

Comment: More info is needed about the configuration of your network (router, mac and one device that fails)

Comment: Hi, have you ever tried: In System Preferences/Energy Saver Setting> Disable “Wake for network access”

Comment: All my devices (2019 Mac, 2018 router, ..) are recents so I guess with last network protocols. I didn't change any settings on my router. so I guess I have the default DHCP settings. I will try to disable  “Wake for network access” on my Mac. But I don't like this kind of bypass.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Were you able to solve it?
Disabling "Wake for network access" didn't work for me

Comment: Also having this issue, MacBook Pro 2019, TP-Link Archer A7 (latest firmware). I didn't have this issue when I was using the TP-Link as an AP but now that I've made it my router this is a regular occurrence unless I disconnect wifi and ethernet from the Mac before it goes to sleep. If I don't the router loses internet and all other devices, wired or wifi lose internet.

I tried the suggestion below of giving the Mac a static IP but that didn't work.

Comment: @Viginti since you seem to possibly have a different router & connection setup I think you should start a new ticket & put a bounty on that. Things I'd want to look at: 1-Update to latest router firmware. 2-make sure Mac isn't setup for Internet Sharing as detailed in answer below. 3-Make sure DHCP is enabled in router & IP address pool offers many IP's. 4-Check any power saving settings in router

Comment: Manuals for A7 & C7 I guess: https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-a7&c7_v5/
 - Advanced > Security > Access Control & IP & MAC Binding I'd disable both of these while troubleshooting
 - Advanced > System Tools > System Log could provide insight
 - Advanced > System Tools > Reboot Schedule could reboot regularly or while troubleshooting to see if the router is just being unstable around the time the mac sleeps

Comment: I have the same problem. Macbook Pro 13" 2018, with USB dock (Verbatim 7 in 1 Dual Type C Hub) which has an ethernet socket. Tried two different TP-Link routers, same symptom as OP when mac goes to sleep with the dock+ethernet cable plugged. Temporary solution is to unplug the dock before letting the macbook go to sleep.

Comment: This is happening to me too. TP-Link Archer router and Pluggable Thunderbolt Dock!

Comment: Same here with Macbook Pro 15" 2016 - Philips 346B1C display (with USB-C dock) - D-Link DIR-882 router. I've learned using Wireshark that the monitor's ethernet port, once macbook goes to sleep, starts putting out ethernet pause frames which then lock up the router. It seems to be the combination of the two problems - display putting out that frames and router letting itself lock up. It might help to turn off flow control on the router, but I can't validate it since the D-Link can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. I had the same issue after connecting my mac laptop to a Dell USB-C Hub Monitor - U2722DE, from which the Ethernet cable was connected to a network switch. My entire network was stopping working soon after my mac laptop was going into sleep mode (before I was using a different docking solution and never had any problem).

To fix, go to System Preferences --> Battery --> Power adapter and disable "Wake for network access". In this way the network on the laptop will not be active, and it will not cause any issue on the rest of the network.
However, if you need to have your network active while in sleep mode, this will not be a viable solution, and I suggest using a different way to connect the laptop to the network

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work, but my intuition tells me that the Mac is trying to override your router as the primary DHCP server. If you don't recall setting that up yourself in any application, the most likely place the DHCP server would be enabled in System Preferences.

Try going to  > System Preferences > Sharing. Click on Internet Sharing in the column on the left, and make sure that the checkbox next to it is unchecked - marked **1** in the screenshot. Also make sure that all the checkboxes on the right column are unchecked - **2** in the screenshot. If that's all done, you should see a red dot and "Internet Sharing: Off" where I've marked **3**. If that red dot was green when you started, that probably means that we've found the culprit.
[image: Sharing Preferences]

Comment: Unfortunately for me this wasn't the issue but maybe for someone else it is. All those boxes were unchecked. I did find [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleWiFi/comments/ip8708/after_macbook_pro_goes_to_sleep_the_entire_home) on Reddit that points to a dock being the issue. I happened to both start using a new router and dock in the same week so in my case it may be my dock causing the issue. I just haven't had time to make wireshark find out. My current resolution is still not allowing the mac to go to sleep.